# How to circle variable to observed (not latent) variables in dagitty plot

Tags: r

How would I put a circle around certaiin variables in the following plot?

```
library(dagitty)
g = dagitty('dag{
  
  A [pos="-1,0.5"]
  W [pos="0.893,-0.422"]
  X [adjusted,pos="0,-0.5"]
  Y [pos="1,0.5"]
  A -> Y
  X -> A
  X -> W
  X -> Y
}')

png("mp.png", width = 500, height = 500,res=300)
plot(g)
dev.off()
```

In the [web based tool](http://www.dagitty.net/dags.html) you can indicate eg latent or adjusted and it changes the color of the circle, but this is not quite what I am looking for, although if it were possible to get these in the plot from R that would be sufficient, although I don't really like the way the variable is next to the circle in the web based version.  I really wanted to circle observed variables and not circle unobserved ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a function which takes the points you want to circle as input, extracts the position of said points and circles them.

```
library(dagitty)

g = dagitty('dag{
  A [pos="-1,0.5"]
  W [pos="0.893,-0.422"]
  X [adjusted,pos="0,-0.5"]
  Y [pos="1,0.5"]
  A -> Y
  X -> A
  X -> W
  X -> Y
}')

circle_points <- function(points_to_circle, g) {
    #few regexs to extract the points and the positions from "g"
    #can surely be optimized, made nicer and more robust but it works for now
    fsplit <- strsplit(g[1], "\\]")[[1]]
    fsplit <- fsplit[-length(fsplit)]
    fsplit <- substr(fsplit, 1, nchar(fsplit)-1)
    fsplit[1] <- substr(fsplit[1], 6, nchar(fsplit))
    vars <- sapply(regmatches(fsplit,
                              regexec("\\\n(.*?)\\s*\\[", fsplit)), "[", 2)
    pos <- sub(".*pos=\\\"", "", fsplit)
    
    #build dataframe with extracted information
    res_df <- data.frame(vars = vars, 
                         posx = sapply(strsplit(pos, ","), "[",1), 
                         posy = sapply(strsplit(pos, ","), "[",2))
    df_to_circle <- res_df[res_df$vars %in% points_to_circle,]
    
    #y-position seems to be inverted and has to be multiplied by -1
    points(c(as.numeric(df_to_circle$posx)), 
           c(as.numeric(df_to_circle$posy) * -1), 
           cex = 4)
}

plot(g)
circle_points(c("A", "Y"), g)
```

This results in:
[image: circled graph]
You can of course work with the cex parameter, adding colors etc. It seems that the positioning of the circles is a bit off-centered so maybe manipulate the x and y positions in `circle_points` by a slim margin.

Answer (score 1):

I did not find any information in `dagitty`, but `bnlearn` package can add circle/or other shape easily. But I just noticed you only want to add circle to observed traits rather than latent variables (better mentioned this in your title). Then my code might not be what you are looking for. I still attached the code here for your reference. Alternatively, you can distinguish observed/latent traits in different color. This can be easily done using `bnlearn` (https://www.bnlearn.com/examples/graphviz-plot/)

```
library(bnlearn)
tree = model2network("[X][W|X][A|X][Y|A:X]")
graphviz.plot(tree, main = "DAG structure", shape = "circle", 
              layout = "circo")
```

[image]